# Mostrar campos de SQL Server en Telegram

Tags: sql-server, python-2.7, ubuntu, telegram

Tengo el siguiente código en python con conexión a base de datos SQLServer hecho en ubuntu(es un bot para telegram):

```
import pymssql
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters

import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

server = '10.248.205.209'
user = 'esolis'
password = 'secret'
database = 'pythonstorage'

conecction = pymssql.connetion(server, user, password, database)
 cur = connection.cursor()
 sql = ' SELECT id,servicio FROM logdaga'
  cur.execute(sql)

def start(bot, update):
    update.message.reply_text('Bienvenido a BotSQL, ¿En que te puedo ayudar?, Para ver mis comandos usa: /help')

def tables(bot, update):
    for row in cur.fetchall():
        resultado = row[0], row[1]
    update.message.reply_text(resultado)
```

Esta tabla `logdaga` tiene 10 registros pero......

Como resultado al ejecutar el comando `/tables` en el bot de telegram me arroja el siguiente resultado:

[image]

Como se ve en la imagen sólo me aparece un registro en vez de los 10 registros que contiene, quisiera saber que estoy haciendo mal :(.

De ante mano les agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: Santiago la linea `update.message.reply_text(resultado)` creo que debe estar dentro del `for`, le falta un nivel de identación. Tal y como está supongo que solo te debería enviar el último registro. Suponiendo que deba enviar todos los registros con una sola llamada a `tables`.

Comment: Hola @FJSevilla , si me sirvio lo tenia mal indentado pero ahora tengo un problemita, si me aparecen todos los campos pero todos salen mensaje por mensaje uno a uno. como lo puedo arreglar ?

Comment: ¿Como quieres que te salgan?¿En un mismo mensaje y cada campo en uno línea?

Comment: si en un solo mensaje, si asi como dices :) como le hago ?

Comment: Santiago perdona, la verdad es que no se como está implementado el método `reply_text` y estoy ahora desde un teléfono que es la mar de cómodo para ver código... :). ¿Si haces `update.message.reply_text('Hola.\nMundo.')` que recibes en Telegram? Lo digo por la posibilidad de usar `join` y crear un string con saltos de linea como mensaje.

Comment: Ok ntp, entiendo, pero ahora intento va :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como lo veo yo, en la última linea `update.message.reply_text(resultado)` está fuera del ciclo `FOR`, por lo que solo te imprime un registro, el último que obtuvo en el ciclo.

```
<!-- language: lang-py -->
def tables(bot, update):
    for row in cur.fetchall():
        resultado = row[0], row[1]
        update.message.reply_text(resultado)
```

Puedes guardar todo en una lista si gustas también.

```
<!-- language: lang-py -->
def tables(bot, update):
    lista = []
    for row in cur.fetchall():
        resultado = row[0], row[1]
        lista.append(resultado)
    update.message.reply_text(lista)
```